# C language coverage report in meson

Tags: c, code-coverage, meson-build

I am trying to get a coverage report in meson. According to the [documentation](https://mesonbuild.com/howtox.html#producing-a-coverage-report), it should be this simple:

First, initialize the build directory with this command.

```
$ meson <other flags> -Db_coverage=true
```

Then issue the following commands.

```
$ meson compile
$ meson test
$ meson compile coverage-html (or coverage-xml)
```

The coverage report can be found in the meson-logs subdirectory.

However, it does not work for me. All steps are okay, except for the last:

```
$ meson compile coverage_html

ERROR: Can't invoke target `coverage_html`: target not found
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: `coverage-html` or `coverage_html` ?

Comment: Same result in both cases.

>> meson compile coverage-html

ERROR: Can't invoke target `coverage-html`: target not found

>> meson compile coverage_html

ERROR: Can't invoke target `coverage_html`: target not found

Comment: Which backend are you using, ninja, xcode, or msbuild? Have you tried invoking them directly through the backend, ie, `ninja -C builddir coverage-html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that part of reference is outdated, I am using ninja backend and have the same behavior:

```
$ meson compile coverage-text -C build

ERROR: Can't invoke target `coverage-text`: target not found
```

However invoking target directly works:

```
$ ninja coverage-html -C build
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[1/1] Generates HTML coverage report
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 7.0.1
  
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: haswell
lcov: LCOV version 1.13
genhtml: LCOV version 1.13
Capturing coverage data from /home/<>/build
Found gcov version: 8.3.0
Scanning /home/<>/build for .gcno files ...
Found 212 graph files in /home/<>/build
Processing aaa.p/bbb.cc.gcno
...
```

Also check if option is correctly setup

```
$ meson configure build | grep cover  
  b_coverage          true
```

and if you have **lcov** or **gcovr** installed

So, the current (minimal) steps to test with coverage report should be:

```
$ meson setup build -Db_coverage=true
$ meson test -C build
$ ninja coverage-html -C build
# or coverage-xml or coverage-text, or just 'coverage' which should generate all 3 if possible
```